# UserAuthName in ServiceStack is null

Tags: servicestack, dotnetopenauth

At which point does session.UserAuthName gets set? I am playing around with the SocialBoostrapApi and login in successfully through Google which calls the OnAuthenticated method. However, UserAuthName is always null. I also don't see a field for it in the Auth tables.

Comment: SocialBoostrapApi have the callback urls pointing to the site that's live this is because it's using the apikeys/secrets created for that app, I recommend you to change those keys for the ones that you own and change the callback urls to localhost, for the username it's supposed that they should be filled in their respective authprovider, but I'm facing the same issue in my application, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200419/servicestack-iauthsession-empty-after-authentication-with-facebookauthprovider